# I have implemented the keycloak sevice for my ionic mobile app development .After generating the release signed apk its not working

Tags: android, apk, release, keycloak, ionic4

My ionic application with `keycloak` service integration is not working after generating the release signed apk.
After launching the generated release signed apk its showing the white screen.

I tried with sample ionic app with `keycloak` service integration and got the same issue after building the signed apk.
Without `keycloak` service integration release apk is working fine.

I am calling the `keycloak` service through https which is hosted in AWS .

I am not sure about why after building the signed apk its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this issue resolved after generating the certificate on keycloak server side.